# Newly installed applications require restart in order to appear in launch menu

Tags: package-management

Most of the times I install any new application on my Ubuntu 16.04, I need to restart my PC in order for that application to appear in my launch menu. Why is it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Terminal opens

Type

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
reboot
```

Hope it helps